# TypeError trying to set model object in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been playing around with the backbone.js + cordova + require.js frameworks, based mainly off of Cristophe Coenraets' [PhoneGap examples on GitHub](https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-day-eu). Displaying my model in a view seems to be straightforward, but I'm still unable to update the model via calls to set or save.

My model looks something like this:

```
SourcePhrase = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // default values
    defaults: {
            id: null,
            markers: "",
            orig: null,
            source: "",
            target: ""
    },

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        if (method === "read") {
            findById(this.id).done(function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            });
        }
    }
}), 
// etc
```

I can pull objects out of my collection by making a call to get:

```
// find and update the model object
var strID = $(event.currentTarget.parentElement).attr('id'); 
var model = this.collection.get(strID);
```

So far, so good:

```
model.set('target', trimmedValue);
```

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '(i=t[r]).callback.call(i.ctx,n,a)')**

Hmm...that's not right. Any idea where I need to start looking to track this down?

EDIT: console output for model just before the call to set:

```
model: Object
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
id: "RUT001-10"
markers: "\hdr"
orig: null
source: "Ruth"
target: "Ruth"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c15"
collection: Object
id: "RUT001-10"
__proto__: Object
strID: "RUT001-10"
```

Comment: Put a `console.log(model)` before the `set`-line. What is the output?

Comment: @msvalkon: Added. It looks like it's doing a by-reference copy (I think that's expected?) -- the collection is set to the collection object.

Comment: You are right, I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's the right method to use, and you can even change your code like this :

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Hi Rida, sorry -- the bind method is still throwing the TypeError, even when adding "this" as the third argument. :-/

Comment: Sorry, I replaced `this.render()` by `this.render`

Comment: Had a chance to try this out, and your code works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I might have tracked it down, maybe? I had in my View for a single item:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render());
    this.render();
},
```

The bind() call was causing the TypeError, which means I might have been running into a "this" issue? ([backbone.js and binding "this"](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this).) At any rate, I've replaced the block with this one:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
},
```

It seems to do the trick. If someone with more backbone.js expertise could comment on this approach, I'd very much appreciate it. Am I doing this correctly?